# Tcl'Tk - почему не работает команда

Tags: tcl

```
    proc Vvod {a} {
           global t
           puts stdout { Vvedite a:}
           set a [gets stdin]
           set t [format "%d" $a] 
}
      proc Ldelete {list value} {
            set ix [lsearch -exact $list $value]
            if {$ix >= 0} {
               return [lreplace $list $ix $ix]
            } else {
               return $list
            }
        }
      proc Bez_X {order} {  
        foreach valume $order {
          set m [lsearch -all $order $valume]
          set y [lrange $m 1 end]
        foreach val $y { 
          lset order $val X
                  }
          set order [Ldelete $order X]         
        }   
          return $order
    }         
      proc Spisok {t} {
        for {set i 1} {$i <= $t } {incr i} {
          set j [expr {round(rand()*$t)}]
        if {$j == 0} {
          set k [expr {$j + 1}]
    }   else {
          set k $j}   
          lappend order $k  
        }
          return $order
    }  
      #proc Ok_spisok {t} {
          #set order [Spisok $t]
          #set order [Bez_X $order]
        #for {set j 1} {$j <= $t } {incr j} { 
          #set order [Bez_X [lappend order $j]]
             #}
          #return $order
    #}       
        while 1 {
        Vvod a
        if {t == n} {
          break}
        #Ok_spisok t
          set order [Spisok $t]
          set order [Bez_X $order]
        for {set j 1} {$j <= $t } {incr j} { 
          set order [Bez_X [lappend order $j]]
             }
         puts stdout "order = $order"   
    }
```

Почему в while не работает proc Ok_spisok {t} {...} если просто код в while работает так как надо...

Наверное должно быть `if {$t == n}`;)
Весь этот код является частью приложения для игры в N-puzzle (N до 99).
В исходном коде который я переделываю N = 15, и порядок чисел строго задан.
GUI приложения уже готов, кроме решения этого вопроса, мне надо сделать так чтобы пазлы двигались при N от 3 до 99. С **ActiveTcl** познакомился почти случайно, в поставке к нему есть *widget.tcl*, где и обнаружил *puzzle.tcl*

Comment: В вашем коде довольно сложно разобраться. Сходу в глаза бросилось if {t == n} - такое условие никогда не выполнится. Наверное, должно быть if {$t == $n}. Изначально при запиливании TCL подразумевалось, что на нем будут писать люди, которые умеют писать на C. А это подразумевает такое качество, как исключительная внимательность. Почему вы хотите сделать то, что вы хотите сделать, именно используя Tcl? Преподаватель заставляет?

Answer (score 0):

```
while 1 {
      Vvod a
    if {$t == n} {
      break } 
      set order [Ok_spisok $t]
      puts stdout "order = $order"   
}
```